# Removing duplicates from autocomplete results Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an issue where I have added two feature classes and it means that I sometimes get results which are duplicated in the autosuggest. I wondered if there is a way I can some how check for duplicates and fetch an alternative instead of showing the same result twice.

This is my code here (working): http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/nHgMX/4/

```
  $(function() {
      jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; 
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
 $.ajax({
          url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
          dataType: "jsonp",
       data: {
        featureClass: ["A","P"],
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 7,
        name_startsWith: request.term,
        country: "UK"
      },           
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                value: item.name
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Any help or information would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the hard part about detecting the duplicates? Your question right now sounds like: "please do it for me". You should show an attempt at doing it, if it doesn't work, post the actual result and what you'd actually want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code slightly so that it does the following:

1. Puts all the autocomplete entries in to an object, with the autocomplete value as the key
2. Converts this object back in to an array and returns it

By doing this, any duplicate keys simply overwrite the previous one.

The `success` function now looks like this:

```
success: function( data ) {
    var x = $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
        return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
        }
    });

    // Create an object to easily filter out duplicates (key of same name will simply be reused)
    var x2 = {};
    for(var i in x) {
        x2[x[i].value] = x[i];
    }

    // Create a new array that simply converts the object in to a de-duplicated array
    var x3 = [];
    for(var i in x2) {
        x3.push(x2[i]);
    }

    // Return the array
    response(x3);
}
```

I have tested it and it seems to be working, although your issue with the duplicates appearing in the first place is not something I can replicate.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nHgMX/8/

Comment: The jsFiddle doesn't work because you have a variable named `new`, even fixing it, I still get duplicates. http://jsfiddle.net/nHgMX/7/ Type Boston in the box, I don't think `obj.value` is what determines equality

Comment: Sorry, this fiddle is my one: http://jsfiddle.net/nHgMX/8/ - will update answer to reflect. When I type Boston in my version, I am only seeing three entries instead of four.

Comment: This is the same suggestion as mine, except that the same code to remove duplicates is abstracted in `_.uniq()`

Comment: The Underscore solution is more elegant.

Comment: + 1 It's the same solution, just abstracted :) I guess `object.value` does give you the identity, since your example doesn't have duplicates anymore

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell exactly what you're asking. But to remove duplicates from an array of objects, you can use underscore's [`_.uniq()`](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq)

```
 $.map( _.uniq(data.geonames, false, function(o){return o.adminName1})
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHgMX/6/) that doesn't show duplicates. But again, it's hard to tell what a duplicate really is from your structure, but this code should move you in the right direction

You don't have use underscore, it's really easy to implement uniq on your own, just look at [azcn2503's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17475138/227299)

Answer (score 2):

If your ajax call is returning an array with the `response` value, you can run it through a plugin to remove duplicate entries. Here's a plugin that I found on another SO thread somewhere a while back.

```
function ArrayNoDupes(array) {
    var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        temp[array[i].value] = true;
    var r = [];
    for (var k in temp)
        r.push(k);
    return r;
}
```

I may be mistaken, but you would implement it into your existing code by changing the following line:

```
source: function( ArrayNoDupes(request), response )
```

EDIT: Updated function per Juan Mendes' comment

Comment: -1 Did you test this? The array is made up of objects. Calling `temp[array[i]]` will call `toString()` on each object and they will all use the same key `[object Object]`

Comment: @JuanMendes No, sorry. Didn't test... baby was waking up and my answer was a bit hasty.

Comment: Changing `temp[array[i]] = true;` to `temp[array[i].value] = true;` will make it work and I will remove the downvote...

Comment: Just remember that `ArrayNoDupes` is not very generic now, it should have a better name